# Breaking curly brackets with 3 equations

Tags: brackets

Anyone know how I can form break 3 equations with curly brackets in this format?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain the question a bit more. Do you want these ellipses as well? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Cheap and easy.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
abc
\[\left.\begin{array}{c}
r1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\
\end{array}\right\}
\raisebox{-1em}{$\left.\begin{array}{c}
r1 \\ 5 \\ 5 \\ 5\\ 5 \\
\end{array}\right\}$}
\raisebox{-2em}{$\left.\begin{array}{c}
r1 \\ 21 \\ 21 \\ 21\\ 21 \\
\end{array}\right\}85$}
\] 
or
\[\left.\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\,}}
r1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\
\end{array}\right\}
\raisebox{-1em}{$\left.\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\,}}
r1 \\ 5 \\ 5 \\ 5\\ 5 \\
\end{array}\right\}$}
\raisebox{-2em}{$\left.\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\,}}
r1 \\ 21 \\ 21 \\ 21\\ 21 \\
\end{array}\right\}85$}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use the macro `\matrix` and the `\lower` TeX primitive:

```
Make a guess
$$
  \def\br#1#2#3#4#5#6{\hbox{$\left.\matrix{#1\cr#2\cr#2\cr#4\cr#5}\right\}#6$}}
  \br{r_1}1111{} \lower 1ex\br{r_1}5555{} \lower 2ex\br{r_1}{21}{21}{21}{21}{85}  
$$
Try 2.
$$
  \def\br#1#2#3#4#5#6{\hbox{$\matrix{#1\cr#2\cr#3\cr#4\cr#4}
        \raise1ex\hbox{\kern-.4em$\left.\matrix{\cr\cr\cr\null}\right\}#6$}$}}
  \br{r_1}2222{} \lower 1ex\br{r_1}9999{} \lower 2ex\br{r_1}{37}{37}{37}{37}{149}  
$$
```